# How to retrieve data from two tables with same column names in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables one working table another one is backup table. Both tables have same columns. Now I want few columns data from two tables in single query.

It is possible in single query?

Table name : `transationdetails` workingtable `transationdetails_backup` is backup table

For Example I write individual queries here:

```
select txnid as txnid
     , date as transactiondate
     , amount as amount 
  from transationdetails;

select txnid as txnid
     , date as transactiondate
     , amount as amount 
  from transationdetails_backup;
```

Expecting Result:

```
select txnid as txnid
     , date as transactiondate
     , amount as amount 
  from transationdetails and transationdetails_backup;
```

Comment: I guess what you described is possible thanks to the `UNION` operator.

Comment: looks to be possible, but difficult to say without knowing sample data.

Comment: Do you want them joined on ID, possibly?

Comment: @Sudipta Mondal check my updated query.

Comment: @durga - looks to be a simple case of using `UNION`. `select .. from table1 union select ... from table2`

Comment: Do you want matching data form the two tables in one row (via a join), or one row for each row in either table (via [set operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Set-Operators.html))? Including sample data and expected results in your question would really help.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal - probably `union all` so duplicates aren't suppressed, but yes it does sound like that *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole - Well its a backup table of transactions, would you want to see the same transaction twice, **maybe**, but it doesn't make that much sense to me. OP hasn't posted sample data for us to infer that anyways.

Comment: @Alex Poole: Not matching. i want fetch all data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SELECT * FROM transationdetails 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM transationdetails_backup;
```

I believe simple UNION ALL would satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

**`select txnid as txnid, date as transactiondate, amount as amount from transationdetails union all select txnid as txnid, date as transactiondate, amount as amount from transationdetails_backup;`**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Concat function same as in MySQL , the easiest way is just put

|| (Double Pipe , between column that you want to join)

```
EX :
select a.id , (a.id||a.name||b.job||a.stats) as backupDetail 
from "FirstTable" as a
inner join "SecondTable" as b on b.id = a.id 
Where a.id="YourParameter";
```

Comment: is this what you want to do?